# Исполнение html страниц на linux сервере

Tags: html, linux

Есть linux сервер. На нем лежит html страница. Каким образом можно ее исполнить, как в обычном браузере, со скриптами и есть ли возможность давать команды получившемуся документу?

Answer (score 3):

> Каким образом можно ее исполнить, как в обычном браузере, со скриптами
>   и есть ли возможность давать команды получившемуся документу?

Правильный ответ - никаким. HTML предназначен только для браузера.
Хотите выполнять какие-либо операции на сервере - используйте серверные скрипты (PHP, Perl, etc).

Comment: И более того - в свойствах  файлов HTML бит "x" не взведён.  Т.е. операционка Вам деликатно намекает. что это НЕ исполнимый файл.